# Simultaneously apply CGAffineTransforms to Translate and Scale?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I’m trying to simultaneously make a `UILabel` larger, and move it off-screen, to create a zoom effect. I’m trying to use the following code to do so, but I’m noticing that I can’t get both of the transforms to animate. In the example below, the `translate` does not animate. By that, I mean that the label jumps immediately to its translated position, then animates the `scale` adjustment. I’ve tried switching the arguments (so, scale first, or scale second) in the `Concat` call, but that made no difference. I’d like both to animate smoothly – what am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)zoom
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                          delay:0.1f
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.6f
          initialSpringVelocity:0.6f
                        options:kNilOptions
                     animations:^{
                         CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
                         CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
                         self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: did you try taking your concat out of the block and just set the final  concat transform in the animation block?

Comment: What do you mean by the final concat transform? `Concat` is only called once. I’ve tried taking the creation of `translate` and `scale` out, yes, no difference I’m afraid.